# query with multiple left joins leading to query lock

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize this query as good as possible,but still i am getting query locks due to this query.Can any one provide some suggestions in improving it.The query fetches the last one day entries from the table.

The QUERY:

```
SELECT CR.id,
       CR.servicecode,
       CR.leadtime,
       CR.redirecturl,
       CRE.custemail,
       CRE.custlname,
       CRE.custfname,
       CRE.duration,
       CR.userid,
       AA.lpintrotimearr,
       AA.lpintrotimedep,
       AA.landdatetimearr,
       AA.landdatetimedep,
       CR.newcustid,
       cre.CRE.custmobilephone,
       CRE.brandname
FROM   response CR
       LEFT JOIN agreement AA
              ON CR.id = AA.id
       LEFT JOIN request CRE
              ON CRE.id = CR.id
WHERE  CR.id > '20120617145243'
       AND CR.approved = 1
       AND CR.chlapproved != 0
       AND CR.chlapproved IS NOT NULL
       AND AA.id IS NOT NULL
       AND ( AA.stdsign != 'on'
              OR AA.stdsign IS NULL )
       AND ( AA.ivaflag = 0
              OR AA.ivaflag IS NULL )
       AND ( AA.opt IS NULL
              OR AA.opt = 0 );
```

The EXPLAIN:

[image: Explain commands result]

One way is to index all 3(AA.stdsign,AA.ivaflag and AA.opts) columns but all the three flags (AA.stdsign,AA.ivaflag and AA.opts) can have only 3 different values.Will indexing these reduce query run time?

All the ids are of varchar(60) data type.

Comment: If would be helpfull if you give us the table definitions using "show creeate table X".

Comment: what do you mean by `but still i am getting query locks due to this query`

Comment: Whenever this query is executed, it takes a lot of time and the process status shows "SENDING DATA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to be improved on the query itself.
On the other hand, setting an index on `AA.stdsign`, `AA.ivaflag` and `AA.opts` should help a lot.

As your `EXPLAIN` indicates, no suitable key is found for your `AA` table and all 534956 rows must be scanned to satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

[edit]
One last tip: using large column types (such as `VARCHAR(60)`) for your primary keys is probably sub-optimal.

First reason: every time you need to reference a row (e.g. in a foreign key), you need another `VARCHAR(60)`.

Second reason: comparisons on strings are slower than on integers (hence it may render a `JOIN` slower than necessary)

You may want to add an `INT` column to your tables, and use it as primary key.

Comment: the problem is all the three flags (AA.stdsign,AA.ivaflag and AA.opts) can have only 3 different values.Will indexing these columns reducing query time?

Comment: Yes, it will. Whether there are two, three, or one thousand different values, MySQL still needs to find out which rows match your condition. Without an index, it has no other solution but scanning the entire table.